# Как откорректировать вывод тестов

Tags: c++, тестирование

У меня проблема с выводом тестов функции на экран . На strdel приходится 60 тестов , 30 на пустую строку , 30 тестов на непустую , как можно откорректировать вывод тестов , ибо у меня выводит лишних 24 на пустую и непустую строку
P.S
Вот сама инструкция к тесту функции
void Strdel(char*
dest, char* src, int
k, int p)
60 тестов (используются все комбинации):

1. Исходная
   строка пуста
2. Исходная
   строка не
   пуста
3. k>0, k<strlen(src)
4. k<0
5. k>strlen(src)
6. k=0
7. k=strlen(src)
8. p>0, p<strlen(src)-k
9. p<0
10. p>strlen(src)-k
11. p=strlen(src)-k
12. p=0
13. p=strlen(src)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char* strdel1(char* str, int p, int k) {
   if ((p <= 0) || (k < 0)) return str;
   int size = strlen1(str);
   if ((k > size - 1) || (p > k))return str;
   for (int i = k; i < size; i++)   str[i-p-1] = str[i+1];
   return str;
}
char* strdel2(char* str, int p, int k)
{
   if ((p <= 0) || (k < 0)) return str;
   int size = strlen1(str);
   if ((k > size - 1) || (p > k))return str;
   int i = k;
   while (i < size) { str[i - p - 1] = str[i + 1]; i++; }
   return str;
}
char* strdel3(char* str, int p, int k) {
   if ((p <= 0) || (k < 0)) return str;
   int size = strlen1(str);
   if ((k > size - 1) || (p > k))return str;
   int i = k;
   while (i < size) { *(str+i-p-1) = *(str+i+1);i++; }
   return str;
}
char* strdel4(char* str, int p, int k)
{
   if ((p <= 0) || (k < 0)) return str;
   int size = strlen1(str);
   if ((k > size - 1) || (p > k))return str;
   for (int i = k; i < size; i++)  *(str+i-p-1) = *(str+i+1);
   return str;

}
int main ()
{
   char* (*Masstrdel[])(char cpy[], int p,int k) = { strdel1,strdel2,strdel3,strdel4 };
       const char* str[] = {"","abcdefg"};
       const int begin[] = {2,-3,9,0,7};
       const int end[] = { 4,-4,6,5,0,7 };
       const int n = sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]);
       const int k = sizeof(Masstrdel) / sizeof(Masstrdel[0]);
       const int startL = sizeof(begin) / sizeof(begin[0]);
       const int endL = sizeof(end) / sizeof(end[0]);
       char tmp[50];
       for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
           cout << "Checking strdel" << i + 1 << endl;
           for (int j = 0; j < startL; ++j) {
               for (int l = 0; l < endL; ++l) {
                   SetColor(7, 0); cout << "Test" << " " << j + 1 << l + 1 << "\n"; SetColor(15, 0);
                   for (int h = 0; h < k; h++) {
                       strcpy(tmp, str[i]);
                       printf_s("strdel%d(\"%s\",%d,%d)= \"%s\"\n", h + 1, str[i], begin[j], end[l], Masstrdel[h](tmp, begin[j], end[l]));
                   }
                   next
               }

           }



}
```

Comment: а что значит "затирание переменной tmp"? вот эта строка `strcpy(tmp, str[i]);` ?

Comment: копирование элемента массива (в нашем случае строку) str[i] во временную переменную

Comment: Если я правильно понял

Comment: м, либо переформулируйте вопрос, либо я не понимаю его.

Comment: все , я написал

Comment: вопрос про "затирание "отпал

Comment: но с количеством тестов пока не понимаю

Answer (score 0):

С кол-вом тестов все ок, их по 30 штук. Просто обратите внимание на их номера. Они начинаются с 11, доходят до 16, а потом 21. Ничего странного не видите?

Ошибка здесь

```
cout << "Test" << " " << j + 1 << l + 1 << "\n";
```

а нужно так

```
cout << "Test" << " " << j *n + l + 1 << "\n";
```